# Observer pattern implementation using Spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, observer-pattern

I'm trying to develop an application where in the people will get notified if there is any change in the PartNumber. Its a Spring based application. Following is the code snippet.

I've abstracted the storing mechanism here in `SaveSubscriptionIF`. The actual details of storing and retrieving are in the implementation class of this interface. The implementation class will be injected by Spring.

The external application calls my `setState()` method- passing the new information.

The `store.getObservers()` method returns me the `Map` which have the Observers and the corresponding info to update.

So far so good. Am struck in the implementation part of `store.getObservers()`. This method implementation needs the `state` data - i.e the new information passed from the external application.

**How do i pass the 'state' data to an implementation class of 'SaveSubscriptionIF'??**

```
public class PartNumberSubject implements Observable {
     private SaveSubscriptionIF store;
     private Object state;
     @Override
     public void addObserver(final ObserverIF o, final Object subscriptionDetails) {
      store.addObserver(o, subscriptionDetails);
     }
     @Override
     public void notifyObservers() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final Map<ObserverIF, List<PartInformationVO>> observers =(Map<ObserverIF,List<PartInformationVO>>) store                 .getObservers();
  for (final Entry<ObserverIF, List<PartInformationVO>> observer : observers
                        .entrySet()) {
     observer.getKey().update(observer.getValue());
     }
    }
    @Override
    public void setState(final Object state) {
     this.state = state;
     notifyObservers();
    }
    }
```

Comment: @Karthik: The Observer interface is not java.lang's. I've created my own interface here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean.

Normally in the observer pattern, the value that changed is passed out as a parameter in the Event object that is created.

So, for example, you could create a `StateChangedEvent` class which had a value in it - state.

Then, your setState method would look like this:

```
public void setState(final Object state) {
    this.state = state;
    notifyObservers(state);
}
```

And notifyObservers:

```
public void notifyObservers(Object state) {
    StateChangedEvent event = new StateChangedEvent(state);
    // Pass this event into each observer which you have subscribed...
}
```

I'm sorry if I've misread the question but this seems to be what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Passing data to observers is done via the observer's methods. So modify your interface:

```
public ObserverIF {
    void update(List<PartInformationVO>, Object state);
}
```

Comment: Actually, i need it only getObservers() method. Because, while fetching the observers list, i need to do some filtering - comparing old and new values. The update() method is fine so far - whatever the info needs to be know, am passing that - List<PartInformationVO>